# ValueError: time data '2018 May 23' does not match format '%Y%b%d' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I know this question has been asked many times and there are many answers. I followed the previous threads, but am still running into an error. I'm trying to convert a list of dates to a format that defines the date as the nth date of the year.

I have a list of times in a pandas data frame that I've defined as:

```
time = data.loc[:, 'date']
```

This prints out dates in the form of '2018 Sep 12', for example. I'm trying to convert these dates to nth day of the year, going back in time from today. So I want these dates to be something like '5 days ago,' '10 days ago,' etc.

When I try to use the pandas datetime module, I'm getting a value error that isn't even recognizing the format, and I'm not sure why. I have:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(time, format='%Y%b%d')
```

but I'm getting a ValueError:

ValueError: time data '2018 May 23' does not match format '%Y%b%d' (match)

I planned to follow that line with the following:

```
new_year_day = pd.Timestamp(year=date.year, month=1, day=1)
day_of_the_year = (date - new_year_day).days + 1
```

though I'm not sure that will get me what I want.

Does anyone know 1) why I'm getting the ValueError, 2) how to fix, and 3) how to format the dates as 'x days ago'?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You missed the spaces in the format, try pd.to_datetime(time, format='%Y %b %d')

Comment: Yes got it! Literally right before you commented. Thanks a billion. Do you have any thoughts on the 2nd bit-- the '5 days ago' conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert the whole column 'date' to a datetime stamp, you can get another column which is the difference between today & the date in days

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y %b %d')
def delta(x):
   dif = today-x
   res=dif.days
   return res
df['days_diff'] = df['date'].apply(delta)
```

if you want, then you take `df['days_diff']` as a list and print them with the text 'days ago' added one by one.

Alternatively, you can use the line below to add the text 'days ago' to column `df['days_diff']` if the days in the past & 'days to go' in the date in the future in the column itself. However, this will convert the type of  `df['days_diff']` from 'int' to an 'object'.

```
df['days_diff'] = np.where(df['days_diff']>=0, df['days_diff'].astype(str)+ 'days ago',df['days_diff'].astype(str)+ 'days to go')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to date time as I mentioned in the comment and use apply to find timedelta

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2018 May 23']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y %b %d')
df['delta'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.to_datetime(x.year, format = '%Y') )
```

You get,

```
    date        delta
0   2018-05-23  142 days
```

Note: The timedelta is a date format and represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times. If you want to concatenate days ago, you need to first convert time delta to string type.

```
df['delta'] = df['delta'].dt.days.astype(str) + ' days ago'
```

Then you get

```
    date        delta
0   2018-05-23  142 days ago
```